# LISTBOX grouping using collectionView Source

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, wpf-controls

`ListBox` grouping using `CollectionView` source programmatically:

like

```
Task 1 (certain date)
Task 2 (certain date)
Task 3 (certain date)
Task 4 (certain date)
```

to

```
Certain date1  
  Task 1
  Task 3  
Certain date2
  Task 2
  Task 4
```

Comment: what does the data actually look like? What do you want the output to look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Matt Sorry for the Late reply,  its just that i need to group list box items based on date, with date as group heading, like People Hub Appin windows phone 7, i  have seen longlist selector , buts thats too big for my Design ,my list box items may/may not have more than 7 to 8 items ( like daily tasks ).

Comment: that answers none of my questions. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for hints on how you can ask a question we can answer

Answer (score 9):

Here is a sample for you.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="695" Width="996" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="lbxTasks" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle />
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private List<Task> MyTasks()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            tasks.Add(new Task { CreatedDate = date, Title = "Task 1" });
            tasks.Add(new Task { CreatedDate = date, Title = "Task 2" });
            tasks.Add(new Task { CreatedDate = date.AddDays(-1), Title = "Task 3" });
            tasks.Add(new Task { CreatedDate = date.AddDays(-1), Title = "Task 4" });
            return tasks;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionView _tasksView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyTasks());
            _tasksView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("CreatedDate"));
            lbxTasks.ItemsSource = _tasksView ;
        }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: THanks for ur reply, i have a listbox which is Binded , indise listbox i have listboxitemtemplete , when i put the    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle />
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>

Comment: continue--- under list box it says The type GroupStyle was not found

Comment: try to Remove DisplayMemberPath="Title" if you have set that attribute in the ListBox

Comment: nope havent set that, just reminding you that this is a windows phone 7 app